# Python Pandas: What causes slowdown in different column selection methods?

Tags: python, benchmarking, pandas, apply

After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916302/selecting-across-multiple-columns-with-python-pandas) about replicating SQL select-statement-like behavior in Pandas, I added [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13419324/567620) showing two ways that could shorten the verbose syntax given in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8916746/567620) to that question.

After playing around with them, my two shorter-syntax methods are significantly slower, and I am hoping someone can explain why

You can assume any functions used below are either from Pandas, IPython, or from [the question and answers linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916302/selecting-across-multiple-columns-with-python-pandas).

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
N = 100000
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.round(np.random.rand(N,5)*10))

def pandas_select(dataframe, select_dict):
    inds = dataframe.apply(lambda x: reduce(lambda v1,v2: v1 and v2,
                           [elem[0](x[key], elem[1])
                           for key,elem in select_dict.iteritems()]), axis=1)
    return dataframe[inds]



%timeit _ = df[(df[1]==3) & (df[2]==2) & (df[4]==5)]
%timeit _ = df[df.apply(lambda x: (x[1]==3) & (x[2]==2) & (x[4]==5), axis=1)]

import operator
select_dict = {1:(operator.eq,3), 2:(operator.eq,2), 4:(operator.eq,5)}
%timeit _ = pandas_select(df, select_dict)
```

The output I get is:

```
In [6]: %timeit _ = df[(df[1]==3) & (df[2]==2) & (df[4]==5)]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.91 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit _ = df[df.apply(lambda x: (x[1]==3) & (x[2]==2) & (x[4]==5), axis=1)]
1 loops, best of 3: 1.23 s per loop

In [10]: %timeit _ = pandas_select(df, select_dict)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.6 s per loop
```

I can buy that the user of `reduce`, `operator` functions, and just the function overhead from my `pandas_select` function could slow it down. But it seems excessive. Inside of my function, I'm using the same syntax, `df[key] logical_op value`, but it's much slower.

I'm also puzzled why the `apply` version along `axis=1` is so much slower. It should literally be just a shortening of the syntax, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `df[df.apply(lambda x: (x[1]==3) & (x[2]==2) & (x[4]==5), axis=1)]`, you're calling your lambda for each of the 100000 rows in the dataframe.  This has substantial overhead as a Python method call must be executed for each row.

When you write `df[(df[1]==3) & (df[2]==2) & (df[4]==5)]`, there's no overhead; instead, the operation is applied to each column in a single operation, and the loop is executed in native code with the potential for vectorization (e.g. SSE).

This isn't exclusive to Pandas; in general, any numpy operation will be much faster if you treat arrays and matrices in aggregate instead of calling Python functions or inner loops on individual items.

Comment: Also, the data has to be boxed as `Series` objects, one for each row.