# Boolean indexing on multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

despite there being at least [two](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) [good](http://manishamde.github.io/blog/2013/03/07/pandas-and-python-top-10/#indexing) tutorials on how to index a DataFrame in Python's `pandas` library, I still can't work out an elegant way of `SELECT`ing on more than one column.

```
>>> d = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y':[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})
>>> d
   x  y
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  4  7
4  5  8
>>> d[d['x']>2] # This works fine
   x  y
2  3  6
3  4  7
4  5  8
>>> d[d['x']>2 & d['y']>7] # I had expected this to work, but it doesn't
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I have found (what I think is) a rather inelegant way of doing it, like this

```
>>> d[d['x']>2][d['y']>7]
```

But it's not pretty, and it scores fairly low for readability (I think).

Is there a better, more Python-tastic way?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It is a precedence operator issue.

You should add extra parenthesis to make your multi condition test working:

```
d[(d['x']>2) & (d['y']>7)]
```

[This section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) of the tutorial you mentioned shows an example with several boolean conditions and the parenthesis are used.

Comment: note: the unary operator `&` is required here. `d[(d['x']>2) and (d['y']>7)]` fails with `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Answer (score 1):

There may still be a better way, but

```
In [56]: d[d['x'] > 2] and d[d['y'] > 7]
Out[56]: 
   x  y
4  5  8
```

works.

Comment: this works, but ends up using python operators (rather than numpy) and so is going to be much slower

Comment: that's a nice solution. I like the fact that it explicitly uses `and`. Makes it clearer that there are two conditions being evaluated.

Comment: Oh, I've just found [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916302/selecting-across-multiple-columns-with-python-pandas) of this question. Whoops.