# Replace row in DataFrame dependant on a value

Tags: python, replace, pandas, dataframe

I would like to replace an entire row in a data, subject to one column in that row satisfying the condition.
i.e. where red is the dataframe

```
['1' 0.0 ' P']
['2' 0.0 ' S']
['3' 64  ' M']
['4' 70  ' M']



red=red.replace(to_replace=' M', value=0)
```

returns the result:

```
['1' 0.0 ' P']
['2' 0.0 ' S']
['3' 64  0]
['4' 70  0]
```

but I would like it to return:

```
['1' 0.0 ' P']
['2' 0.0 ' S']
['3' 0  0]
['4' 0  0]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) to filter out the part of the DataFrame you want to zero, and then assign the value to it. Below, it selects all lines where `c` column value is `'M'` and it takes all columns from `b` to `c`, and set the value of this selection to `0`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1', 0.0, 'P'],
    ...: ['2', 0.0, 'S'],
    ...: ['3', 64,  'M'],
    ...: ['4', 70,  'M'],], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df.loc[df['c']=='M','b':'c'] = 0

df
Out[54]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  0  P
1  2  0  S
2  3  0  0
3  4  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how to select values in a range ?

df.loc[ df['c']>0 and df['c']<1,'b':'c'] = 0 will raise an error

Comment: You forget the parenthesis, please see [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17216674/624829)