# Fill NaN with a known value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a Dataset containing 3 columns, example as follow:

```
       User         Items         Item_ID

0      U265          PC             1
1      U299         Table           2
2      U299          PC            NaN
```

I would like to fill nans with a known value depending on the column Items.
PC has an ID of 1 so I want python to look for NaNs in Item_ID, check if the column Items is not NaN, if it's good, check the Item_ID of the wanted Item from a previous row then fill the NaN with the value.

I'll get at the end:

```
       User         Items         Item_ID

0      U265          PC             1
1      U299         Table           2
2      U299          PC             1
```

Any ideas ? should I use the map function ? groupby also to take the most used value in for and Item so I don't fill in with noise/wrong values ? It's twisted :)

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

You can access a set of rows by logical arrays.

```
df.loc[df.Items == "PC"]
```

You can even combine several conditions, see [Python Pandas: Boolean indexing on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216153/python-pandas-boolean-indexing-on-multiple-columns)

```
df.loc[(df.Items == "PC") and numpy.isnan(df.Item_ID)]
```

Then you can set the value and join it back into the old dataframe like this

```
df.update(
    df.loc[(df.Items == "PC") 
           and numpy.isnan(df.Item_ID)]
    .assign(Item_ID=1)
)
```

Or for the last step you can use another way which suits better to the structure of your data.