# Change entire pandas Series based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

In my pandas DataFrame I want to add a new column (`NewCol`), based on some conditions that follow from data of another column (`OldCol`).

To be more specific, my column `OldCol` contains three types of strings:

1. BB_sometext
2. sometext1
3. sometext 1

I want to differentiate between these three types of strings. Right now, I did this using the following code:

```
df['NewCol'] = pd.Series()
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if str(df.loc[i, 'OldCol']).split('_')[0] == "BB":
        df.loc[i, 'NewCol'] = "A"
    elif len(str(df.loc[i, 'OldCol']).split(' ')) == 1:
        df.loc[i, 'NewCol'] = "B"
    else:
        df.loc[i, 'NewCol'] = "C"
```

Even though this code seems to work, I'm sure there is a better way to do something like this, as this seems very inefficient. Does anyone know a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you need something like the following formulation:

```
>>> df.loc[boolean_test, 'NewCol'] = desired_result
```

Or, [for multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17216674/2071807) (*Note the parentheses around each condition, and the rather unpythonic `&` instead of `and`*):

```
>>> df.loc[(boolean_test1) & (boolean_test2), 'NewCol'] = desired_result
```

#### Example

Let's start with an example `Data.Frame`:

```
>>>  df = pd.DataFrame(dict(OldCol=['sometext1', 'sometext 1', 'BB_ccc', 'sometext1']))
```

Then you'd do:

```
>>> df.loc[df['OldCol'].str.split('_').str[0] == 'BB', 'NewCol'] = "A"
```

To set all `BB_` columns to `A`. You could even (optionally, for readability) separate out the boolean condition onto its own line:

```
>>> oldcol_starts_BB = df['OldCol'].str.split('_').str[0] == 'BB'
>>> df.loc[oldcol_starts_BB, 'NewCol'] = "A"
```

I like this method become it means the reader doesn't have to work out the logic hidden within the `split('_').str[0]` part.

Then, to set all columns with no space, which are still not set (i.e. where `isnull` is true):

```
>>> oldcol_has_no_space = df['OldCol'].str.find(' ') < 0
>>> newcol_is_null = df['NewCol'].isnull()
>>> df.loc[(oldcol_has_no_space) & (newcol_is_null), 'NewCol'] = 'C'
```

Then finally, set all remaining values of `NewCol` to `B`:

```
>>> df.loc[df['NewCol'].isnull(), 'NewCol'] = 'B'  
>>> df
       OldCol NewCol
0   sometext1      C
1  sometext 1      B
2      BB_ccc      A
3   sometext1      C
```