# Python return the first index where multiple columns contain a desired value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have the following sample data frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'seq':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
    'flag1':[np.nan,np.nan,1,1,1, 0,-1,-1,1,1,1,0],
    'flag2':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,0, 0,0,-1,-1,0,1, 0,1]
})
```

I am trying to get the index of the first row where both `flag1` and `flag2` values are `1`. In the above case, it would be `9`.

I tried `df[df.flag1 == 1.0 & df.flag2 == 1.0].index[0]` but it returns me an error. Similarly, `df[df.flag1 == 1.0] & df[df.flag2 == 1.0].index[0]` does not work either. I tried searching on SO but could not find a solution for my specific need.

Comment: "that returns me an error" .  Please include the exact error message in your question.

Comment: Here is a relevant SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216153/python-pandas-boolean-indexing-on-multiple-columns/17216674

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this expression:

```
df.flag1 == 1.0 & df.flag2 == 1.0
```

the `&` operator has greatest precedence, so it is actually interpreted as:

```
df.flag1 == (1.0 & df.flag2) == 1.0
```

which is entirely not what you meant, and in this case produces an error.

Add parentheses to force the evaluation order you want:

```
(df.flag1 == 1.0) & (df.flag2 == 1.0)
```

With this change, your initial approach should work fine.