# how to iterate over a pandas groupby object while using if statement in python

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe df which looks like this:

```
| source_num| source_date| text      | category    |location    | source |
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+---
|  0      | 15/12/2020 | text1       | cat 1       | loc1       |soucrce1|
|  1      | 15/12/2020 | text2       | cat 2       | loc2       |source 2|
|  2      | 15/12/2020 | text3       | cat 3       | loc2       |source 3|
|  3      | 15/12/2020 | text4       | cat 2       | loc3       |source 2|
| ...     | ...        | ...         |             |            |        |
```

When running GroupBy function
Then filter for the specific values in **location** it returns the correct answers.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['category','source_num',"source","location"], as_index = False).aggregate('sum')

 grouped.loc[grouped["location"] == "loc2"]
```

My question is that how can i perform a filter more than one like this:

First filter :

```
grouped.loc[grouped["location"] == "loc2"]
```

Second filter :

```
grouped.loc[grouped["location"] == "loc2" & grouped["category"] .str.contains('cat1')]
```

Third filter:
....

**I think I can perform these above filter by iterating over the **groupby** with **if/else statement** object  right ??**

EXCPECTED RESULT after the filtering based on the first and second filter:

```
| source_num| source_date| text      | category    |location    | source |
+---------+------------+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+---
|  0      | 15/12/2020 | text2       | cat 2       | loc2       |soucrce2|
|  1      | 15/12/2020 | text3       | cat 3       | loc2       |source 3|
```

Where the first filter is done  and the second is not meet the **if statement** so the system its not entering into the second filter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas: Boolean indexing on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216153/python-pandas-boolean-indexing-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: Please read the documentation at the link below and state what you have already tried and where you currently are.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Comment: @skuzzy no i want like for statement to iterate over the result of the **groupby** then based on the several if /else statement the last result will display the final result.

Comment: @skuzzy i do not understand what i have with the indexing ??

untill now i am able to get the groupby object than perform the first filter..

what i want is to be able to perfrom several filter and return the final result as one dataframe ....

maybe i can perform each filter aside then combine all the results from each filter in one dataframe  is this can be done ??

Comment: You don't need a for-loop iteration to apply conditional tests - one or many. 
The results of `groupby` are also in a valid dataframe and follow the same indexing rule as any other. pandas dataframe  Please refer to the links in my comments to see how boolean indexing works with one or many conditional clauses.
Pandas strongly advise against itreation over a dataframe - 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#iteration

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `for` loop with `if/statements` loop through the `grouped` object

```
for name, grouped in grouped:
   if ...
```

Comment: so based on your answer in the `if/statement` i put 
`if (grouped.loc[grouped["location"] == "loc2"]):
      grouped.loc[grouped["location"] == "loc2"]
elif (grouped.loc[grouped["location"] == "loc2" & grouped["category"] .str.contains('cat1')]):
      (grouped.loc[grouped["location"] == "loc2" & grouped["category"] .str.contains('cat1')] 
else:
        ....`

Comment: correct; however, remember an if statement checks a bool not array, you can use `all()` to get a bool for `(grouped["location"] == "loc2").all()`

Comment: but where i use **name**

Comment: it doesn't look like you need need it, print it as your looping and see

Comment: i tried and it crash and display the below error:
`ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-83aeadeaa384> in <module>
----> 1 for name, grouped in grouped:
   
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`