# pandas: iterative filtering a DataFrame's rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a `DataFrame` like so,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['x', 1, 2], ['x', 1, 3], ['y', 2, 2]], 
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

To select all rows where `c == 2` and `a == 'x'`, I could do something like,

```
df[(df['a'] == 'x') & (df['c'] == 2)]
```

Or I could iterative refine by making temporary variables,

```
df1 = df[df['a'] == 'x']
df2 = df1[df1['c'] == 2]
```

Is there a way to iterative refine on rows?

```
(
  df
  .refine(lambda row: row['a'] == 'x')     # this method doesn't exist
  .refine(lambda row: row['c'] == 2)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't a solution for now, in pandas version 0.13 you'll be able to do

```
df.query('a == "x"').query('c == 2')
```

to achieve what you want.

You'll also be able to do

```
df['a == "x"']['c == 2']
```

and

```
df['a == "x" and c == 2']
```

What's wrong with

```
df[(df.a == 'x') & (df.c == 2)]
```

until 0.13?

Comment: @AndyHayden No, if I understand you correctly. In the case of chaining you'll call `query` as many times as you chain. I don't think there's a sane way to, say, turn a chain into an "`and`-ing" of the expressions in the `[]`

Comment: It's just a stylistic preference. Method chaining makes my code clearer. Will pandas 0.13 allow me to filter on arbitrary functions of rows, rather than simple comparisons on individual columns via the `DataFrame.query` syntax?

Comment: Probably not. Right now function calls are not implemented in the parser. `query` yields large speedups for big arrays (> 10000 elements) by using `numexpr`, which doesn't support arbitrary function calls (it supports a few `numpy` math functions and `where` IIRC). Other backends could support arbitrary callables, but that hardly seems worth it just for style, although I could be convinced to implement it once the core `query` code is merged. Alternatively, a method on `DataFrame`s could be added to do what you want (chained selection) but this seems like it will be inherently slow.

Comment: @AndyHayden It sounds like you're talking about lazy evaluation, which is a much broader topic than `eval`/`query`. I'm looking at the `filter` method and wondering if something like that for `DataFrame` *content* (as opposed to the axes) might be useful. I wouldn't be opposed to `refine`...

Comment: @PhillipCloud that's exactly the phrase which was eluding me last night. Very broad topic for sure. Not sure I follow re content vs axis.

Comment: @AndyHayden I just meant that `DataFrame.filter` filters axes information (e.g., columns matching a regex) whereas a `DataFrame.refine` method would filter based on the values in the `DataFrame`. Similar to the difference between `DataFrame.rename` and `DataFrame.replace`.

Comment: I'm not in a position to comment on implementation speed (you both would know far better than I), but the inherent redundancy of refering to `df` three times in `df[(df.a == 'x') & (df.c == 2)]` feels off. Even something along the lines `df.into(lambda df_: df_[df_.a == 'x]).into(lambda df_: df_[df.c == 2])` might make sense. This is an idiom I see frequently in Scala, where collections were designed explicitly for use with method chaining.

Comment: Attribute access is an amortized constant time operation (it's a `dict` lookup) unless you overload `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__` with something slower than that. In the case of `DataFrame`s (and `Series` in `pandas >= 0.12`) attribute access is overloaded as a lookup using the index (which is backed by khash hash tables), which I believe also provide amortized constant time lookup. So, there are no performance penalties for attribute access in this case, it's just not aesthetically pleasing to look at :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number of terms; the number of which you don't know until runtime, you can do as below. I am not saying this is at all a beautiful way to achieve the goal but I can't see an alternative with Pandas 0.14.1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['x', 1, 2], ['x', 1, 3], ['y', 2, 2]],
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

conditions = {'a': 'x', 'c': 2}

def esc(term):
    if isinstance(term, str):
        return '"%s"' % term
    return str(term)

q_parts = ["%s == %s" % (k, esc(v)) for k, v in conditions.items()]
q = ' and '.join(q_parts)

print df.query(q)
```

Of course, the esc function or the wider snippet would need to be extended further to handle logical-NOT, is x in (x, y, z), etc...