# How to apply single condition to a list of columns in a dataframe and add value to 4th column without using multiple OR's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I  need to apply a single condition to 3 columns of a dataframe and change value of 4th without using or statement .

I can do with `np.where` but if the no of columns is big it's going to take a lot of time

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,3,6,7],'c':[4,6,4,1], 'd':['p','f','p','u'],'e':['a','a','b','c']})

df['d'] = np.where(df.a > 4 | df.b > 4 | df.c > 4 , 'p',df['d']) 

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5],'b':[1,3,6,7],'c':[4,6,4,1], 'd':['p','f','p','f']})
df['d']=np.where(df.a > 4 | df.b > 4 | df.c > 4 , 'p','f')
```

I need someway of implementing same condition `> , <` to list of columns without using or for each.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selecting across multiple columns with python pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916302/selecting-across-multiple-columns-with-python-pandas)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are tying to accomplish. Are you trying to change the value of the fourth column if the condition of applied to the three columns is true?

Comment: Yes right but I want to do it without using multiple or.. The actual column has 30 + columns and 25th column will change if 20 columns have data on all rows > 250. Using 20 or is not practical

Comment: your condition is same for all column? like you want all columns to be greater than same value(i.e. 4 in your example)?

Comment: yes . right .. just to note columns involved for condition checking  is not equal to  the all columns in the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DataFrame.gt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html#pandas.DataFrame.gt) along with `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,3,6,7],'c':[4,6,4,1], 'd':['p','f','p','u'],'e':['a','a','b','c']})

# create a subset of a dataframe on which you want to check condition
new_df = df[['a','b','c']]
mask = new_df.gt(4).any(axis=1)  # check if any value is greater than 4

df['d'] = np.where(mask, 'p','f')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e                                                                                                                      
0  1  1  4  f  a                                                                                                                      
1  2  3  6  p  a                                                                                                                      
2  3  6  4  p  b                                                                                                                      
3  4  7  1  p  c
```